# Why is my RxJS subscribe error handler not firing?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am attempting to utilize Angular 2's HTTP methods in a service which is working fine until the server returns an invalid response.  Here's the method code from my service:

```
getCalcCode(request: CalculatorRequest) {
  this.http.post(this._serviceUrl, JSON.stringify(request), this.options)
    .map((response: Response) => response.json().returnData as CalculatorResponse)
    .catch((error) => {
      return Observable.throw(error);
    })
    .subscribe((response: CalculatorResponse) => {
      if (response.returnCode === '000') {
        console.log('Code is zero!');
      }
    }, (error) => {
      console.error('Error: : ', error);
    });
}
```

When the server returns an invalid response, the `Map` operator returns undefined, therefore, when attempting to access `response.returnCode` from within my subscribe method, I receive:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'returnCode' of undefined

And the asynchronous code simply stops executing...the error function on subscribe is never called (**EDIT: because the server is responding properly and the mapping is working properly, just to the wrong JSON format**).

What can I do to ensure that errors within subscribe are caught from my error handler?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

After discussing this in the comments further, what I'm truly asking here is exactly how to catch errors from within my "subscribe" callback?  Will I simply need to use a try/catch block?

Comment: Are you sure the server returns a response with an HTTP error code (so > 200)?

Comment: It seems you already have figured out everything. Your error callback is no executed because your success callback is executed. It's one or the other, never both. It just seems your map() callback and/or your success callbackand/or your backend has a bug that needs to be fixed.

Comment: Yep, the server is actually responding with a status code 200, just with incorrect JSON.

Comment: @JBNizet -- fair enough, I guess I am over thinking this as I didn't realize that the call is succeeding, the error handler ISN'T going to get called.  Is there any way to tell whether map fails or returns undefined and throwing an error then?

Comment: I think response.json().returnData is returning undefined. Your json object doesn't have returnData in it, but there are no errors, so the catch block is never reached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The description in comments is actually a bit inaccurate. When the source emits an error then the callback to the `map()` operator is never called and the error is just send further (`map()` works only with `next` signals, not `error`s). The "one or the other, never both" rule applies only to `error` and `complete` signals, not to `next` signals. Of course, you can have multiple `next` signals.

Then it's caught by `catch()` and just rethrown.

1. You don't need to be using `catch()` at all for this. The error is propagated as `error` notification already.
2. The server probably doesn't send proper status codes so Angular HTTP service interprets them as `next` notifications. If the server sends for example `404` or `500` status codes it'll be automatically propagated as errors and you don't need to do anything.

Comment: This perfectly answered my question, as well as another question I had.  I was curious about whether utilizing the "catch()" operator was necessary, as in whether the error would be passed along to the subscribe event handler.  Thank you!!

Comment: @martin maybe you misinterpreted what I said, or I didn't express myself correctly. Either an error is emitted, and the error callback of the subscribe method is called, or it's a regular event, and the success callback of the susbscribe method is called. You can't have both being called for the same event. There is a single event being emitted here, and the OP expected both the success and error callbacks to be called. That can't happen.